# Typescript - getting the type embedded in the function type parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using an imported type definition with the following function type definition with some sort of complex parameter type:

```
export interface SomeTypeDefinition {
  someFunction: (
    param1: string,
    param2: {
      key1: number,
      key2: string,
      key3: {
        key4: boolean
      }
    }
  ) => number;
}
```

When I implement this interface, do I need to copy and paste the input parameters into the implementing function like so (or creating my own interface and using that):

```
function myImplementingFunction(p1: string, p2: {
  key1: number,
  key2: string,
  key3: {
    key4: boolean
  }
}): number;
```

Or is there some way of getting the parameters? Something like this, which obviously doesn't work:

```
function myImplementingFunction(p1: SomeTypeDefinition['someFunction']['param1'],
    p2: SomeTypeDefinition['someFunction']['param2']):
    SomeTypeDefinition['someFunction']['return'];
```

The function type definition did not include a separate type key for param2, which is why I was wondering about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TypeScript's built-in [`Parameters<>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) and [`ReturnType<>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) utility types:

```
function myImplementingFunction(
  p1: Parameters<SomeTypeDefinition['someFunction']>[0],
  p2: Parameters<SomeTypeDefinition['someFunction']>[1],
): ReturnType<SomeTypeDefinition['someFunction']> {
  // ...
}
```

See it in action in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=14&ssc=193&pln=14&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZQgFtgAVATzGABFh1kEYEIk4BvAKDjgGdjgAYgFck2JiwBccABRducMJiiYiARik8YUZAHMANHO6LlRAExTO8%20QGtg5dXCRCiAIzQGr3W%20XO8tuj09vAGYLQyC7ABYpFwgIABtgTCRw7gBfcIzuAEo4AF4APkdnNygAbg4MjnQRMWZWInIASSIwRJIUXWFRcSRpMAcABSUVYFQoHgAeQhIKKlp6JEZ6gG0Acj4SbrqWNYBdApWABj29BV9hkzG0KZmySho6Bl71zcFa3v3D1T3sqQAlMZCKBIObAab8MELZ6rDb8bafA7sNJAA).